# Definition of null sets in Lie groups

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, lie-groups, haar-measure

Suppose $G$ is a Lie group and $A\subseteq G$. Suppose moreover that $(U_i,\varphi_i)$ is a cover of $G$ by charts. I know of two definitions for whether $A$ is a null set or not:

- $A$ has Haar measure zero.
- $\varphi_i(U_i\cap A)$ has Lebesgue measure $0$ for every $i$.

For the sake of this question, let's say $A$ is Haar null if it satisfies the first definition and Lebesgue null if it satisfies the second. I am sure these two definitions are equivalent, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Clearly, $A$ is Haar null if and only if $A\cap U_i$ is Haar null for every $i$, so we can assume $A\subseteq U$ for some $U$ which admits a diffeomorphism $\varphi: U\to \Bbb{R}^n$, and ask whether $A$ is Haar null if and only if $\varphi(A)$ is Lebesgue null.

I'm pretty sure I know how to prove that if $A$ is Lebesgue null then it's also Haar null. For some differential form $\omega$ on $G$, the Haar measure of $A$ is $$\int_G \chi_A \omega=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}(\varphi^{-1})^*\chi_A \omega=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}(\chi_A\circ\varphi^{-1})(\varphi^{-1})^* \omega=\int_{\Bbb{R}^n}\chi_{\varphi(A)}(\varphi^{-1})^* \omega=0.$$
(Since $\varphi(A)$ is Lebesgue null).

So I have two questions:

> - Is my proof correct?
> - How do you prove every Haar null set is Lebesgue null?

I am sure this is trivial if you are familiar with these things. Perhaps you can say something about the the differential form $(\varphi^{-1})^* \omega$ in relation to $\wedge dx_1\cdots\wedge dx_n$?

Comment: Your proof is correct. The converse implication follows from the fact that $\omega$ is a $C^\infty$-volume form, i.e. is nowhere zero.

Comment: And why is it a $C^\infty$-volume form? Because every open set has positive measure?

Comment: This is because of an explicit construction of $\omega$: Start with a volume form $\omega(e)$ on $T_eG$, and then extend it to the rest of $G$ by left translations, $\omega(g):= dL_g(\omega(e))$. Then check that this form satisfies axioms of the Haar measure.

Comment: I think I understand the construction, I am just not sure why the fact $\omega$ is never zero implies that if $\int \chi_B (\varphi^{-1})^*\omega=0$ then $B$ is of Lebesgue measure zero. Again, I am sure this is trivial if you understand the theory of differential forms properly...

Comment: When you unravel this formula, you see that it amounts to integrating a strictly positive (or strictly negative) function on the subset $B$.